# Singleton Classes in Coq

Tags: singleton, coq, typeclass

I don't really understand singleton classes in Coq. I am currently looking at the following definition:

```
Class Decision (P : Prop) := decide : {P} + {¬P}.
```

As far as I undestand this creates the singleton class `Decision P` and a function `decide: forall (P: Prop), Decision P -> {P} + {¬P}`.

But how do I create inhabitants of `Decision P` which I seem to need to use `decide`? There does not seem to be any constructor.

Comment: I never worked with Coq—only Haskell and Isabelle—but judging from [this tutorial](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/draft/qc-current/Typeclasses.html) the `Class` keyword defines a **typeclass**. Now, if you want to make something a member of the typeclass `Decision` you have to declare an **instance**: `instance DecidableT : Decision T {decide := ...}.`.

Comment: Now that you say it, it is so bloody obvious that I don't know how I missed that. Thank you very much.

Comment: @FK82 Would you care to add your comment as an answer?

Comment: @AntonTrunov Sure! Thanks for pinging me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, from my understanding `Class` is used to define a **typeclass**.

Following [this link](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/draft/qc-current/Typeclasses.html), if you want to make something a member of your type class `Decision` you have to define an **instance** as well:

```
instance DecidableT : Decision T {
    decide := ...
}.
```